# Where can i find the php-amqp documentation?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

We are planning to use RabbitMQ from PHP, and we decided to go with php-amqp, because it supports PHP 5.2. The only problem is i can't find a proper documentation for this PECL library

Comment: Define "proper documentation?" For what exactly are you looking?

Comment: API documentation and examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sad to say, but official php-amqp documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php) was removed as it was obsoleted. For now you can look through [stub files](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/tree/master/stubs) and [tests](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/tree/master/tests).

*I'm really sorry that we don't write proper documentation and examples yet.*

If you will have further questions about [`php-amqp`](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp) extension feels free to post more questions here or contact me personally.

Comment: Yes, this is it. But it is outdated (https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/issues/17), so read stubs too.

Comment: @zaq178miami I have used methods for sending and receiving messages. It is working on terminal properly. but When I try to run on web browser receiving code does not response it continuously waits.

Answer (score 0):

The official RabbitMQ site hosts a great [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html), but unfortunately the included code examples are using the [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) library, which is a pure PHP implementation of a RabbitMQ client.

Fortunately, the same examples are available for a variety of languages and libraries on the [rabbitmq-tutorials](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials) GitHub repository, even included [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp), the PECL extension mentioned in the above question.