# Do to block consumer on empty queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, consumer

**Specifics**

I have consumer, written in PHP, which tries to consume messages. My goal is simple as - if there are no messages in the queue, release the execution and continue, considering there was "no data retrieved".

**Current thoughts**

I tried [`AMQP_NOWAIT`](http://php.net/manual/pl/amqp.constants.php#AMQP_NOWAIT) flag, like:

```
$flag = AMQP_NOWAIT;
$this->queue->consume($callbackFunction, $flag, $this->consumerTag);
```

And it didn't work. So far, I have workaround, like - I am declaring connection timeout for [\AMQPConnection](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.amqpconnection.php), as, let's say, 5 seconds, and then catching it in this way:

```
try {
    $this->consumer->consume($this->consumer->getReadMessageCallback($notifications, $requeue));
} catch (\AMQPConnectionException $connectionException) {
    //based on timeouts. Are there other ways to interrupt empty queue consuming? AMQP_NOWAIT fails, does nothing:
    return [];
}
```

But, that is a very "hacky" way to do it. It's working for me, but:

- Still blocking code for `timeout` seconds
- Will obviously fail, if I will have too many messages (i.e. it won't be able to finish till timeout will end).
- More, it's not even documented, so relying on this should be last resort.

Next - I tried `AMQP_IFEMPTY | AMQP_PASSIVE` on queue creation. The thing is - it will delete queue if there are no messages there, and it will raise an exception (which I may catch) on attempt to get messages from there. But then there is a problem like - queue is immediately deleted and I can not even add messages there.

**Question**

Reading messages from empty queue is really a common issue, thus I'm sure it should be a way to resolve it in a proper matter. Thus, how would I do that?

*Yes, manual links are `/pl/` as there are no "en" links. But it's more or less readable as it is in English there in any case.*

Comment: can I ask what's the problem with blocking wait? it's a consumer...

Comment: I want to change that behavior. It's part of API. Let's say I want to just retrieve messages (and requeue them back) - like it's done in admin. tool for RabbitMQ. Actually, if they are doing it somehow on empty queues, then it's for sure possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to figure out whether queue empty or not, you can call `AMQPQueue::declare()` which is idempotent and in result returns messages count in queue. Note, that number is not pretty accurate (see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684848/rabbitmq-get-total-count-of-messages-enqueued/17686861#17686861)).

In addition, you can just call `AMQPQueue::get()` (behaves like it's done in admin tool).

And after that all, as you also tried, you can set `AMQPConnection::setReadTimeout()` to some low value (in local net 1 sec may be enough), and then call `AMQPQueue::consume()` and catch timeout exception if consumer waits too long.

As to poor documentation, see answer to this question: [Where can i find the php-amqp documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23101343/1461984).

Comment: Curious, my only "documentation" was exactly those stubs which I've installed for PHPStorm. So it's you to thanks for at least them. I think `::get()` is exactly what I need according to my model. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry that we didn't write any docs yet. Stubs was made by numerous contributors and we try to keep at least them up to date. Now all our efforts are on proper AMQP protocol implementation and codebase consistency, which is sometimes a bit tricky. I hope in this year we'll update docs and add some example, at least I have card in my trello about it and there are issue on github about that.

Comment: Well, anyway, I'm using those stubs and they were able to guide till this point (so, almost working application with all features needed). I also remember all those answers, linked here, as I was using them. Unfortunately, I can't thank more that give one or two upvotes..